# NextJS component level SASS styling

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, sass, next.js

I am working on a simple NextJS app, but I am having trouble with component level styling using SASS/SCSS. Everything looks fine when the user first lands on the page, but when the user navigates to a page `/about` for example or from `/about` to `/`, the component styles didn't get render, the user needs to refresh the page to see the styles

⚙️ *SETTINGS*

`./package.json`

```
"dependencies": {
  "@zeit/next-css": "1.0.1",
  "@zeit/next-sass": "1.0.1",
  "autoprefixer": "^9.7.0",
  "next": "^9.3.1",
  "node-sass": "4.13.1",
  "react": "^16.13.0",
  "react-dom": "^16.13.0",
  "webpack": "^4.42.0"
}
```

`./next.config.js`

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');
const withCss = require('@zeit/next-css');

module.exports = withCss(
  withSass({
    webpack(config) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.(eot|woff?2|ttf|otf|svg|png|jpe?g|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 100000,
          },
        },
      });
      return config;
    },
  }),
);
```

`./postcss.config.js`

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
  plugins: [autoprefixer],
};
```

*PAGES*

`./pages/index.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import Home from '../components/Home';

class Index extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    <Layout>
      <Home />
    </Layout>
  }
}

export default Index;
```

`./pages/about.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import Layout from '../components/Layout';
import Company from '../components/Company';

class About extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    <Layout>
      <Company />
    </Layout>
  }
}

export default About;
```

*COMPONENTS*

`./components/Layout.js`

```
import React from 'react';
import AppBar from '../AppBar/AppBar';
import './Layout.scss';

class Layout extends React.PureComponent {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <AppBar />
        <main className="Layout">
          {children}
        </main>
      </>
    );
  }
}

export default Layout;
```

`./components/Layout.scss`

```
.Layout {
  background: #f00;
}
```

`./components/AppBar.js`

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import './AppBar.scss';

export default () => (
  <header className="AppBar">
    <Link href="/">
      <a>Home</a>
    </Link>
    <Link href="/about">
      <a>About</a>
    </Link>
  </header>
)
```

`./components/AppBar.scss`

```
.AppBar {
  background: #0f0;
}
```

`./components/Home.js`

```
import './Home.scss';

export default () => (
  <div className="Home">Home</div>
)
```

`./components/Home.scss`

```
.Home {
  background: #00f;
}
```

`./components/Company.js`

```
import './Company.scss';

export default () => (
  <div className="Company">Company</div>
)
```

`./components/Company.scss`

```
.Company {
  background: #ff0;
}
```

Comment: Can you see the "Network" tab requesting the files?

Comment: When the user navigates from a to b, there is no CSS request, but when the user refreshes the page, there is a CSS request of `http://localhost:3000/_next/static/css/styles.chunk.css?ts=158...` 

Comment: I _think_ you should import it as a "variable", then call it, like this: `import css from "../styles.scss"  
export default () => <div className={css.example}>Hello World!</div>`

Comment: I tried doing it as a module `<Component className={styles.Name} />`/, the same issue is happening. Also, in one of my SCSS, I am importing modules CCSS. 

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I fix my issue.

With the release of Next.js 9.3, there is no need for `@zeit/next-sass` & `@zeit/next-css`. 
I also do the following:

- add `styled-jsx-plugin-sass node-sassa` as dev-dep
- create a `.babelrc` file and add the following:

```
{
  "presets": [
    [
      "next/babel",
      {
        "styled-jsx": {
          "plugins": ["styled-jsx-plugin-sass"]
        }
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

So I have two options to do it:

- add my sass/scss on the `<style jsx>`
- rename my component sass/scss file to `<ComponentName>.module.scss`

The second option is a pain in the A, you need to `import styles from './ComponentName.module.scss` and add element class as `className={styles.ComponentName}` or `className={styles['ComponentName-button']}`.

Comment: yeah this is nice, but what if I want to use CSS framework classes both with custom component classes eg. 

`className="col-sm-4 bg-success  mycomponent__custom-class"`

Comment: Well, since `col-sm-4 bg-success` are global, you can do `className={'col-sm-4 bg-success ${styles['ComponentName-custom']}'}` 

Comment: I agree that importing .module.scss files and adding classNames to everything is a pain. Do you know if you can configure NextJS like Create-React-App in which all you have to do is import the .scss file? I would prefer to just use .scss files over .module.scss or styled-jsx.

Comment: There is a ticket for this issue on the Nextjs repo itself, you can check it regularly for updates  https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/14672

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is looking for a working answer after nextjs 11. You can refer to  this [repo](https://github.com/justgeek/nextjs-global-sass), or read full details in this [article](https://dev.to/justgeek/using-nextjs-with-sass-the-angular-way-3f7l)

Here is full next config code that I have used

```
const withTM = require('next-transpile-modules')([]);

const withPlugins = require('next-compose-plugins');

const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');

module.exports = withPlugins([withTM], {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    // Find and remove NextJS css rules.
    const cssRulesIdx = config.module.rules.findIndex((r) => r.oneOf);
    if (cssRulesIdx === -1) {
      throw new Error('Could not find NextJS CSS rule to overwrite.');
    }
    config.module.rules.splice(cssRulesIdx, 1);

    // Add a simpler rule for global css anywhere.
    config.plugins.push(
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        // Options similar to the same options in webpackOptions.output
        // both options are optional
        filename: 'static/chunks/pages/[contenthash].css',
        chunkFilename: 'static/chunks/pages/[contenthash].css',
      }),
    );

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
      use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
    });

    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.tsx/,
      use: [defaultLoaders.babel],
    });

    return config;
  },
});
```