# Next.js with SCSS split to files for each component

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I'm new in Next.js, regular to work with create-react-app (ejected).
With the configuration in create-react-app I was able to work with SCSS not in CSS-module approach, but with split SCSS files.
For example:

**ComponentA.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ComponentA.scss';

const ComponentA = () => {
}
```

**ComponentB.jsx**

```
import React from 'react';
import './ComponentB.scss';

const ComponentB = () => {
}
```

I have read the following:
https://medium.com/@vladymyr.pylypchatin/the-simple-way-to-use-scoped-and-global-scss-with-next-js-67cdb2d0c676
[NextJS component level SASS styling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60752431/nextjs-component-level-sass-styling)

But these solutions don't fit my needs.

**My question:**
There is a a way to write local SCSS files for each component, with put CSS-module approach or `<style jsx>` approach, just import SCSS (like in the example I added) for each component?, (I'm aware of the scoping issue, I will manage the class names manually by myself). 
**But keep the bundle to one large CSS file when the bundle is built,** as webpack does.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you clarify why the solutions you mentioned don't fit your needs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were almost there, you can use the css module by importing the scss file with a name.

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './ComponentA.scss';

const ComponentA = () => {
   return <div className={style.blockOne}>A</div>
}
```

And

```
import React from 'react';
import style from './ComponentB.scss';

const ComponentB = () => {
   return <div className={style.blockOne}>A</div>
}
```

Then when you build your app with typescript, it will put all the style within the same file as your logic, including the css.

Example of generated app from typescript

```
...
var Button = function (props) {
    return (React.createElement("button", { form: props.form, type: props.type, onMouseOver: props.onMouseOver, className: "" + style$1.button + (props.className ? " " + props.className : "") + (props.disabled ? " " + style$1.disabled : "") + variableClass(style$1, props.removeShadow ? "removeShadow" : ""), onClick: props.onClick, disabled: props.disabled },
        props.leftIcon ? (React.createElement("div", { className: style$1.leftIcon }, props.leftIcon)) : null,
        React.createElement("div", { className: style$1.buttonValue }, props.children),
        props.icon ? React.createElement("div", { className: style$1.icon }, props.icon) : null));
};

var css_248z$2 = ".style-module_input__3-5Pc {\n  display: flex;\n  background: var(--input-background);\n  border-radius: var(--border-radius-input);\n  padding: 10px;\n  box-shadow: inset 0 2px 2px #0000001c; }\n  .style-module_input__3-5Pc input {\n    border: none;\n    width: 100%;\n    font-family: var(--txt-font);\n    background: var(--input-background);\n    padding: 0px; }\n    .style-module_input__3-5Pc input:focus {\n      outline: none; }\n  .style-module_input__3-5Pc .style-module_icon__1UUS9 {\n    padding-left: 5px;\n    color: var(--main-txt-color); }\n";
var style$2 = {"input":"style-module_input__3-5Pc","icon":"style-module_icon__1UUS9"};
styleInject(css_248z$2);
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You should try `styled-components` if you want to use scss it makes easier to work with the components.